# What if union of disjoint sets results in universal set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I have a question related to set theory.

If $A_1,A_2,A_3\dots, A_n$ belongs to universal set $U$, and if all of the sets are disjoint i.e. $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for all $i$ and $j$.

And If their union equals to Universal set i.e. $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots A_n = U $ = Universal set.

What is such situation called?

Comment: It's called a Partition!

Comment: @Bjørn: If none of the sets is empty, of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer.Sorry couldnt acknowledge answer as I was not well.My hearty thanks and sincerest apologies to naslundx,bjorn and asaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every $A_i$ is nonempty, you have described a **[partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)** of the set $U$.

The definition holds for any set, not just for the current universal set. If the union of disjoint (non-empty) sets equal any set $X$, we say in the same way that we have a partition of $X$.

Comment: You have to require that none of the $A_i$ are empty, though.

Comment: @asafKaragila Thanks, added that information.